# Stop Python exe script from converting back

Tags: python, pyinstaller

For example, I have a Python file like this:

```
print("Hello World")
```

Now I am converting it to an .exe file using pyinstaller.

But I found a method to convert it back:

> Use pyinstxtractor.py:
>
> `python pyinstxtractor.py yourFileName.exe`
> This will extract .exe and create a folder named yourFileName.exe_extracted.
>
> Inside the yourFileName.exe_extracted folder, find the file without
> any extension.
>
> Edit it with HxD editor and from any **pycache** file created with the
> same version of Python, copy the first row and insert it into your
> file.
>
> Save and Rename the file with .pyc extension.
>
> Decompile the compiled bytecode (.pyc) to .py using any online tool,
> like https://www.toolnb.com/tools-lang-en/pyc.html

Is there any way to prevent converting the .exe file converting back to his .py file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an obfuscation tool such as PyArmor and add at-least some level of code-protection to your original python script.

The official documentation of PyArmor has more info on this here https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#bundle-obfuscated-scripts-to-one-executable-file

Comment: ... but at the end of the day you cannot fully protect your code no matter what you try.

Comment: @luk2302 completely agree :) But one can make it as hard as possible if they choose to do so.